# Testing a decorated API route in Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators

I have the following simple controller

```
@companies.route('/companies/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
@inject_repository(CompanyRepository)
def get_company(repository, id):
    """
    GET /companies/id
    """
    company = repository.get(pk=id)
    return jsonify(company.to_json())
```

The DAO is being injected by `@inject_repository(CompanyRepository)`

I do not, however, get what is happening at test time:

```
def test_get_company(self):

    response = self.client.get(url_for('companies.get_company', id=1))
    data = json.loads(response.get_data(as_text=True))

    assert_equal(response.status_code, 200)
```

I get the following error

`TypeError: get_company() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'`

Isn't the controller being decorated?

---

Decorator code

```
def inject_repository(repository_class):

    def decorator(func):

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            if 'psql' in class_init_fields(repository_class):
                repository = psql_repository_for(
                    repository_model=repository_class,
                    connection_meta=current_app.config['POSTGRESQL'])

            else:
                raise ValueError("'{}' repository cannot be injected".format(repository_class.__name__))

            return func(repository=repository)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Comment: Where is `inject_repository` from? Can you show the code?

Comment: I have edited @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the arguments on from your decorator to the decorated function.

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
    kwargs['repository'] = repository
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, thanks for the help @DanielRoseman

Why was the API working properly though? The exception was just being thrown when testing.